# Applying Filters on Result

Tags: java, servlet-filters, ninjaframework

I'm developing an application using the Ninja Framework (http://www.ninjaframework.org), and I have a use case where I want to add CORS headers to *all* responses on a given path. Filters sound perfect for this, as they are applied automatically, so I don't have to worry about accidentally forgetting to add these headers.

However, from what I'm reading, filters are applied before control passes to the controller method, and there is no way to alter the `Result` once it is returned.

Is there a way I can modify all `Result`s going out from my app without having to keep writing boilerplate in all my controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I misinterpreted the documentation/guide.

`filterChain.next(context)` return a `Result`, which can then be modified further, and the returned `Result` will be what is effectively written to the wire.

A note to other readers: when multiple filters are used to annotate a controller method, just as the request descends these filters left-to-right in the annotation, the response ascends back right-to-left, meaning the first filter to take effect going in will be the last filter to take effect going out.